# Wordcloud in R without "tm"

Tags: linux, r, tm, word-cloud

I was trying to use Wordcloud without "tm" package, since it is supported on   versions 3.1 and above, but most linux systems have R 3.0.8 installed by default (from the apt repository). So i was thinking to convert a file of words in data.frame to TermDocumentMatrix Object. Please Help. If there is a package to help in 3.0.8, please specify.

Comment: I suggest you read Matt Gemmell's excellent introduction on how to ask for help on technical problems, found here: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com). I do not intend to be rude, it is actually very good.

Comment: Also: [How to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) from the SO R FAQ

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade R if there is such a requirement? There's [info](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/) for pretty much every distribution on how to get the latest packages.

Comment: Does the qdap package run on your system, so you can create the tdm you need?  Then wordnet can convert it to the matrix object it needs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to upgrading R (via [hrbmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr)) or using the `qdap` package (via [lawyeR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583119/lawyer)), I would recommend the `quanteda` package, which depends on the `wordcloud` package to easily create wordclouds. You could create a wordcloud something like this, where `text_vector` is a vector of texts (or a column from a matrix or data frame):

```
library(quanteda)
my_dfm <- dfm(text_vector, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("English"))
plot(my_dfm)
```